# Python program not working when run in a SSH session

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, ssh, pip

So I have a Python program stored on a remote server (which is running Ubuntu Server 18.04) . When I use VNC Viewer to remote control the server and run the python program inside a terminal (in that VNC session), everything work great.

But when i created a SSH connection and try to run that same program inside my terminal windows on my local machine it will not work as I expected.

So the command was like this:
`python3 main.py --train`

And here is the error:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(main.py:24109): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 09:45:07.931: gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(main.py:24109): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 09:45:07.932: gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
tf.estimator package not installed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from models import Model, DecoderType
  File "/home/kop/handwriting/src/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from md_lstm import multi_dimensional_rnn_while_loop
  File "/home/kop/handwriting/src/md_lstm.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import RNNCell, LSTMStateTuple
  File "/home/kop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import distribute
  File "/home/kop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.distribute.python.tpu_strategy import TPUStrategy
  File "/home/kop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/tpu_strategy.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import tpu
  File "/home/kop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu.keras_support import tpu_model as keras_to_tpu_model
  File "/home/kop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/keras_support.py", line 67, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator import model_fn as model_fn_lib
  File "/home/kop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    import tensorflow.python.estimator.estimator_lib
  File "/home/kop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator_lib.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs import inputs
  File "/home/kop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/inputs.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs.numpy_io import numpy_input_fn
  File "/home/kop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/numpy_io.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs.queues import feeding_functions
  File "/home/kop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/queues/feeding_functions.py", line 40, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/kop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    plot_params = pandas.plotting._style._Options(deprecated=True)
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'plotting'
```

I tried to re-run `pip install` some packages inside my SSH session but it does not solve the problem.

I also tried to run `python3` and try to import `tensorflow` and `pandas` which I thought it will be the source of the problem and it still can import that packages:

[image: lol i can import those packages and it said it can't find it ???]

So I think that there are maybe some think wrong about the `PATH` of those packages so that I can't run the program, but I don't know how to fix that and I also can't find anything related to my problem on the internet ... so I really need you guys help here.

Keep in mind that the **user** that I used when I do **remote control** and the **user** when I use **SSH connection** is the **same user**.

Thanks you so much for your help.

Comment: If you are able to import `pandas` in the interactive shell, but get an error when running the script, then the problem is somewhere in your code and not in the environment setup. Can you try running `from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import RNNCell, LSTMStateTuple` from the remote shell to confirm this? If the import succeeds, you need to provide a [mcve] from your code.

Comment: I tried to run `from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import RNNCell, LSTMStateTuple` from the remote shell and it working fine. The file contain that call is actually not written by me but this guys:  https://github.com/philipperemy/tensorflow-multi-dimensional-lstm/blob/master/md_lstm.py. What I can do to help you debuging this part ? Thanks @hoefling

Comment: Digging further up the stack trace, I downloaded the script and am able to run `python -c "from md_lstm import multi_dimensional_rnn_while_loop"` from the remote shell. Check whether you can do the same; if the import succeeds, the error sits either in `main.py` or in `models.py`.

Comment: I'm able to run the same command too. So in the `models.py` file, i imported that piece of code by `from md_lstm import multi_dimensional_rnn_while_loop` and in the `main.py` file, i imported the `models.py` code by `from models import Model, DecoderType`. Everything is in a same folder. What could go wrong here ?

Comment: so if you create files, say, `models2.py` with the contents `from md_lstm import multi_dimensional_rnn_while_loop class Model: pass class DecoderType: pass` and `main2.py` with the line `from models2 import Model, DecoderType` and run it with `python main2.py`, you can already reproduce the error?

Comment: @hoefling is that really necessary ? Keep in mind that I can run all of these code without any problem when i'm in a VNC session and using the terminal on the server itself. Just need to make thing clear before I try to create that `models2.py` files

Comment: Thing is, you didn't provide a [mcve] that reproduces the error and I can't reproduce it locally using only the stack trace you provided. Clearly, the error lies either in your code or in your environment (env vars? config files?), but without knowing what's inside, it's hard to say what's wrong. If I create files using the code you provided, I can't reproduce the error using `tesnorflow==1.5.1` and `pandas==0.23.4`.

Comment: There are a lot of thing going on in that code, it will take me a while to create a **mcve** version of my code and i'm working on that. Btw, i'm using `tensorflow==1.10.1` and `pandas==0.23.4`.

Comment: @hoefling I created `models2.py` and `main2.py` and I can't reproduce the error